# Monitoring Azure Functions in realtime?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-functions-core-tools

Application Insight gets my function's logs with minimum 3 minutes delay. I realised that log-streaming service (available in each function) shows the logs in real time. But that's not very convenient. Is there any other way to get logs in real time?

Also according to Azure, Application Insight perform its tasks in near-real time. Having 3 minutes delay, I'm wondering how can it do its tasks in near real time?

P.S: my function app is quite simple and doesn't do heavy task.

Comment: Use log.info and push it into a azure sql or a eventhub and then retrive it whereever needed

Comment: Considering the amount of data it processes, I would say that 3 minutes qualifies as "near realtime" for Application Insights. As @HariHaran writes if you need log streaming in another console than the Application Insigts Live Log Stream pane, then you have push the log messages into something else.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using "Live Stream" feature of Application Insights:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream